# CakePHP 3.x paginate associated model (belongsToMany)

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i have a model Deals wish is associated with Cities model (belongsToMany), end i fetch a city coresponding on ID with the deals associated with the city , in the DealsTable i have the fetch function :

```
public function findByCity($city){

    return $this->Cities->get($city , ['contain' => ['Deals']]);
}
```

and in the DealsController i want to paginate the deals associated to the city fetched , what the approche i don't find a solution in the cakePHP 3 book.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to paginate the associations. I would do something like this:

```
$city = $this->Cities->get($city);
$deals = $this->paginate($this->Cities->Deals->findByCityId($city->id));

return ['city'=>$city, 'deals'=>$deals];
```

Comment: belongsToMany has not an foreign key , but a table for the association , CitiesDeals , but i don't found an solution to paginate the associated model, so i have already do this logic , i get the city id from the associated table the i paginate the deals from those ids , thnks man :)

Comment: @ZakariaWahabi, don't forget to mark this as the solution.

Comment: this isn't a right answer , this isn't what i want , i have already do this logic but i wanted a technique to paginate the associated model , not to fetch an foreign_id then fetch by this id and paginate :)

Comment: @ZakariaWahabi - I gave you the answer that it is not possible to paginate associated models in the CakePHP framework. That is the correct answer. I just went ahead and took the time to show you how the best way to get around it.

Comment: I could careless about reputation @ZakariaWahabi. What I care about is making sure questions on here actually have an answer selected to help other people who come across this.